# How to convert a String Fraction "2/6" into two integers? Java

Tags: java, string, integer, java.util.scanner, fractions

I'm doing a Fraction Calculator, i already have all the code for the operations.

But now i want to create a `Scanner` that takes a `String` and converts the `String` into 2 `Integers` (Numerator AND Denominator).

The user input `String` should be in this format: Number / Number. If it's something else i'll make the scanner appear again.

The code i already have can handle negative `Integers` so the `-` sign and the `0`shoudn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to split the String based on the delimiter, in this case `/`, and then [`String.trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) the output and parse them to get the numerator and the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the String on "/" and extract the numerator and denominator in the following way.

```
public void scan(String string){
 if(string.matches("-{0,1}[0-9]+\\/[0-9]+"){
  String[] numbers = string.split("/");

  int numerator = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
  int denominator = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
 }
 else{
  scan(string);
 }
}
```

Comment: in this case what would happen if the user inputs "Three/12" or something else without '/'?

Comment: I have added a condition which would call the scan again if it is not in the format of number/number.  But I do not understand how exactly you would want to handle the else case. Following the above approach would lead to an infinite loop during no match.

Comment: i can take care of the else statements, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: When the format of string is invalid, it will cause a stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Pattern with a regular expression, which at the same time, enforces a correct formatted string, and enables you to extract Numerator and Dominator:

```
Pattern inputPattern = 
    Pattern.compile("\\A(?<numerator>-?\\d+)[ ]*\\/[ ]*(?<denominator>-?\\d+)\\z");
Matcher matcher = inputPattern.matcher(inputString);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    //valid inputstring
    int numerator = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group("numerator"));
    int denominator = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group("denominator"));

} else {
    letTheScannerAppearAgain();
}
```

The pattern used here contains two named groups marked by rounded brackets `(..)`, and separated by a slash (escaped because slash also has a meaning in a regex `\/`)
Numerator/denominator may start with a minus sign, and should contain at least one digit. Spaces before and after the slash are allowed.

Comment: I think this is the best answer, i don't have much experience with java.util.regex.Matcher and java.util.regex.Pattern since this assigment is for a basic Java course. but i'll read more about this. Thanks!

Comment: I would do it this way but with beginning-of-input and end-of-input symbols (`\\A` and `\\z`) rather than start-of-line and end-of-line symbols (`^` and `$`), because the way you have it, a string like `"5/5\n6/7"` would also be matched.

Comment: I also recommend using named capture groups and optional spacing between the numbers (that's more of a judgement call based on what you want your acceptable format to be), so in my case the regex would become `"\\A(?<numerator>-?\\d+)[ ]?\\/[ ]?(?<denominator>-?\\d+)\\z"`, and with this regex, the group access becomes `matcher.group("numerator")` and `matcher.group("denominator")`. Just easier to keep track of if the regex ever changes.

Comment: Cool, named groups! Didn't know about that. Updated my answer with your suggestion, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just did like this:

```
int fTop, fBottom;
Fraction(String frak) {
    fTop = Integer.parseInt(frak.substring(0,frak.indexOf('/')));
    fBottom = Integer.parseInt(frak.substring(frak.indexOf('/')+1,frak.length())); 
}
```